# Windows RT - Are button click events executed on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a button click event in my xaml which fires:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e){
     StoryBoardName.begin()
 }
```

I am curious if I should be wrapping this "StoryBoardName.begin() like so:

```
var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>{
    StoryBoardName.Begin();
});
```

or if that would just be superfluous?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Events raised by the UI are processed on the UI thread.

In fact, because of the way that the thread is set up (SyncronizationContext), you can even use [async/await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) to perform asynchronous work on other threads but still have the UI code run on the UI thread as needed without much more complexity.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StoryBoardName.Begin();
    IsEnabled = false;
    await webClient.GoGetAWebpageAsync();
    IsEnabled = true;
}
```